The big difference between before and until

I did my homework before you came- it was finished before their arrival

I did my homework until you came- here because of 'until" it simply means doing homework was in progress up till their arriving and  homework wasn't done. Correct? It has the same meaning as " I was doing my homework until". Yes?




1: I did my homework before you came
would normally imply I completed my homework before you arrived


1a: I was doing my homework before you came
would normally imply I stopped doing my homework when you arrived
(the homework probably isn't finished)


2: I did my homework until you came
same as 1a above
2a: I was doing my homework until you came
same as 1a above

As you can see, the form of the verb is at least as important as the choice of until or before. Also note that with the continuous verb form (was doing) the default meaning would be the same with when instead of before or until. If you wanted to convey that you'd done (all, or some) homework significantly before the addressee arrived, you'd probably use completely different phrasing.

Yeah so simply unitl forces an action to be in progress even if written in simple past

+1.  No, Artur, until does not "force an action to be in progress".  In "I caught a glimpse of it until you came" , until does not force that momentary action to be prolonged.  Rather, until makes no sense when used with caught a glimpse.  until is compatible with ongoing actions.

@TimR: Good example. I can just about get my head around I was catching a glimpse of it until you got in the way, but it's more than a little "odd". And I was just about to catch a glimpse of it until you got in the way is somewhat "challenging", too.

Buti  still for instance " I   painted the wall/ was painting the wall until" convey the same meaning no matter which tense is used but with "before" there would be a differnce in meaning. Right?

I'm not sure if you've understood this or not. #1 I painted the wall before you arrived doesn't mean the same as #2 I was painting the wall before you arrived (#1 implies the job was finished). But  #3 I painted the wall until you arrived and #4 I was painting the wall until you arrived both mean the same as #2 (I didn't finish the job).

Yeah I know thank you very much for help
